# Is there a way to truncate the microseconds of a CSV value when importing data using LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I'm loading data using LOAD DATA INFILE in 5.5 where the value includes microseconds. I must use DATETIME data type. Currently, I'm using regular expressions to remove them from the CSV prior to import. I'm wondering if there's an option in MySQL to truncate them so it only loads YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Up until 5.5, `DATETIME` columns store only second precision.

Comment: 5.5. Hence needing to remove it before I load.  - I've updated the question to reflect it.

Comment: I don't think you do (need that.) Just try to load a small file first and check the resulting table. It should have no fractional seconds in the datetime values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables to edit your input data for example.

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file name ' INTO TABLE table (@var1) SET
>   Date=str_to_date(@var1,'%Y-%m-%d')

You can use this method for a lot of different stuff like loading only the 3 first char of a string or doing some mathematical funcion etc.

Example

> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file name' INTO TABLE table (@var1) SET
>   Date=substring(@var1,1,3).

Hope this helps